# Alternative Solutions to “American Billions” like puzzles: Find a 9-digit number (no repeats), where the first  digits give a number divisible by 

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, divisibility

I recently came across the question:

A nine-digit number $x_1$$x_2\cdots x_9$ is formed using each of the digits $1,2,3,...,9$ exactly once. Reading left to right for each $x_1\cdots x_i$, i divides that number exactly. Find the number.

Stated in another way:

$$x_1x_2 \equiv 0 \mod 2$$

$$x_1x_2x_3 \equiv 0 \mod 3$$

$$\cdots$$

$$x_1x_2\cdots x_9 \equiv 0 \mod 9$$

I solved this question in a very similar way to solution presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287382/find-the-9-digit-no-containing-digits-1-to-9-exactly-once-such-that-n-di) even getting this intermediate form

$$x_1 4 x_3 2 5 8 x_7 6 x_9$$
$$y_1 8 y_3 6 5 4 y_7 2 y_9$$

and then I tried out the possibilities until I landed on the solution.

My solution and many of the ones I have seen feel very ad-hoc with lots of trial and error. I was wondering if there were more direct and/or elegant solutions (especially using modular arithmetic).